# Cambiar comas por puntos en un spinner

Tags: php, mysql, html5, bootstrap

Estoy realizando una aplicación web y me gustaría que apareciesen los datos decimales con punto o con comas pero siendo en todo la aplicación coherente ya que los datos de la base de datos aparecen con puntos y en el spinner con comas. Me gustaría saber como puedo hacer para que aparezca todo igual ya sea cambiando la configuración del spinner o la de la base de datos(Mysql).

```
<label id="stockL" for="stock"> Peso por unidad: </label>
<input type="number" id="stock" name="stock" value="<?php echo $Peso ?>" 
class="form-control" step="0.25" style="width:100px" min="0" value="0" required/>
```

Comment: No deberias cambiar la configuración de la base de datos ya que tu problema es totalmente de vista, lo mas simple es que cambies tu `spinner` para que tenga el formato que tu deseas, aunque no es estrictamente necesario que sea igual, pero si asi lo deseas cambia el spinner

Comment: Hola, gracias por contestar. ¿Cómo se podría cambiar el formato en el spinner?

Comment: Ok, para eso tendrias que mostrarnos tu codigo, para que la solución no sea tan intrusiva, y sea la mas facil de implementar para ti

Comment: En este momento voy a editar tu pregunta, esto es con el fin de que se encuentre todo mas ordenado, le sea mas facil a otras personas ayudarte, en el futuro puedes agregar cualquier información editando tu pregunta original :)

Comment: Otra pregunta tu spinner es el de [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/spinner/) o es de algun otro framework o lo hiciste a mano?

Comment: Muchas gracias por editarlo. El spinner es del framework de bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

Bueno lo que entiendo es que quieres presentar el spinner con punto en vez de coma, por lo que no es recomendable cambiar la base de datos, si quieres cambiar la presentación del spinner puedes usar jquery para presentar el spinner de la forma que deseas, podrías hacer algo asi:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Decimal Spinner</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#spinner" ).spinner({
      step: 0.25,
      numberFormat: "n"
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<p>
  <label for="spinner">Decimal spinner:</label>
  <input id="spinner" name="spinner" value="0">
</p>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por contestar. He incluido el código que me indicaste pero no me llama a la función. Como tendría que hacer para llamar a la función?

Comment: Bueno si quieres cambiar la visualizacion, podrias tratar de cambiar la cultura, en el siguiente enlace hay un ejemplo: https://jqueryui.com/spinner/#decimal

Comment: Me confundí, yo siempre lo he visto con puntos y pensé que OP quería comas, pero no. Parece que está bien, pero no lo he probado en un navegador en español.

Answer (score 0):

No es una respuesta pero es demasiado largo para comentario.

> los datos de la base de datos aparecen con puntos

Esto sugiere una confusión de fondo, que importa aclarar. Estamos hablando, supongo, de datos **numéricos** con punto decimal [*]. Ahora bien, qué quiere decir eso de que "en la base de datos aparecen con puntos"?

Lo primero que debes aclarar(te) es : cómo se está guardando el dato en la DB? ¿como un string (cadena de caracteres=texto) o como un tipo numérico (DECIMAL, NUMERIC, REAL, etc)?

Si lo primero, estamos en problemas de diseño. La DB debe usar el tipo de dato "correcto".

Si lo segundo, entonces está bien, pero tu inquietud de que "aparezca igual en la db" que en la página web no tiene mucho sentido. Lo que "aparece en la DB" es simplemente lo que te muestra tu aplicación que estás usando para ver la DB (eg, un cliente desktop como MySQL Workbench, o un cliente web como PhpMyAdmin). Está bien que el "locale" de esa aplicación según tu preferencia, pero eso no tiene NADA que ver con tu página web.

[*] Ojo: un número de tarjeta de crédito, por ejemplo, o un teléfono o un ´codigo postal, no son datos propiamente numéricos; son sólo textos, cuyos caracteres estan restringidos a dígitos decimales. Los datos numéricos son aquellos que, por ejemplo, tiene sentido sumar y restar.

Comment: En la base de datos está como número, no como string. Yo lo que estoy tratandode hacer es internacionalizar por eso quiero que se muestre con punto o con coma dependiendo del idioma que haya escogido.

Comment: "del idioma que haya escogido" quien? el usuario o tu?  En la pregunta dices querer que "que aparezca todo igual". Por otro lado, que hables de cambiar "la configuracion de la base de datos" me sugiere que tienes un error de conceptos que traté de aclarar.

Comment: El idioma lo escoge el usuario. Una vez escogido querría que en el spinner cambiase de coma a punto o viceversa.

Comment: Entonces fijate aquí: http://api.jqueryui.com/spinner/#option-culture

Comment: Aquí hay un ejemplo (mira el codigo fuente) https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/spinner/decimal.html

Comment: Ok, muchas gracias. Voy a probarlo. Valdría también para un input de tipo date?

Comment: No. La conversión de un tipo numérico en tu capa web a su formato html depende de lo que estés usando en esa capa. Si estàs impriendo directamente desde php, puede usar http://php.net/manual/es/class.numberformatter.php